# Add time interval values in new column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have a large pandas dataframe (40 million rows) with the following format :

```
ID                    DATETIME             TIMESTAMP
81215545953683710540  2017-01-01 17:39:57  1483243205
74994612102903447699  2017-01-01 19:14:12  1483243261
48126186377367976994  2017-01-01 17:19:29  1483243263
23522333658893375671  2017-01-01 12:50:46  1483243266
16194691060240380504  2017-01-01 15:59:23  1483243353
```

I am trying to assign a value to each row depending on the timestamp so that i have group of rows with the same value if they are in the same time interval.

Let's say I have `t0 = 1483243205` and I want a differently value when `TIMESTAMP = t0+10` . So here my time interval would be of 10.

I would like something like that :

```
ID                    DATETIME             TIMESTAMP  VALUE 
81215545953683710540  2017-01-01 17:39:57  1483243205 0
74994612102903447699  2017-01-01 19:14:12  1483243261 5
48126186377367976994  2017-01-01 17:19:29  1483243263 5
23522333658893375671  2017-01-01 12:50:46  1483243266 6
16194691060240380504  2017-01-01 15:59:23  1483243288 8
```

Here is my code :

```
df['VALUE']=''
t=1483243205
j=0

for i in range(0,len(df['TIMESTAMP'])):
    while(df.iloc[i][2])<(t+10):
        df['VALUE'][i]=j
        i+=1  
    t+=10
    j+=1
```

I have a warning when executing my code (SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame) and I have the following result :

```
ID                    DATETIME             TIMESTAMP  VALUE 
81215545953683710540  2017-01-01 17:39:57  1483243205 0
74994612102903447699  2017-01-01 19:14:12  1483243261
48126186377367976994  2017-01-01 17:19:29  1483243263
23522333658893375671  2017-01-01 12:50:46  1483243266
16194691060240380504  2017-01-01 15:59:23  1483243288
```

It is not the first time I encounter the warning and I always overcame it, but I am confused with the fact I only got a value for the first row.

Does anyone know what I am missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using pandas' cut method to achieve this, preventing the need to explicitly loop through your DataFrame.

```
tmin, tmax = df['TIMESTAMP'].min(), df['TIMESTAMP'].max()
bins = [i for i in range(tmin, tmax+10, 10)]
labels = [i for i in range(len(bins)-1)]

df['VALUE'] = pd.cut(df['TIMESTAMP'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)

                      ID               DATETIME  TIMESTAMP  VALUE
0   81215545953683710540    2017-01-01 17:39:57 1483243205      0
1   74994612102903447699    2017-01-01 19:14:12 1483243261      5
2   48126186377367976994    2017-01-01 17:19:29 1483243263      5
3   23522333658893375671    2017-01-01 12:50:46 1483243266      6
4   16194691060240380504    2017-01-01 15:59:23 1483243288      8
```